Blazor parent does not update chilld
I`m using Fluxor for state management for my NET8 Blazor WASM app. My parent component passes down state from the store to the child component via an input parameter.
parent
@page "/people"
@inherits Fluxor.Blazor.Web.Components.FluxorComponent
@inject IState<PeopleState> _state

<ShowPeople Requests="_state.Value.People.ToArray()"></ShowPeople>

child
@foreach(var person in People)
{
    <div>@person.Name</div>
}

@code {
    [Parameter] public Person[] People { get; set; } = [];
}

state excerpt
public record PeopleState
{   
    public bool IsLoading { get; init; }
    public bool IsLoaded { get; init; }
    public string? Error { get; init; }
    public DateTimeOffset LoadedAt { get; init; }

    public List<Person> People { get; init; } = [];
}

public class PeopleFeatureState : Feature<PeopleState>
{
    public override string GetName() => nameof(PeopleState);
    protected override PeopleState GetInitialState() => new();
}

public record RejectPerson(string Id);
public record RejectPersonSuccess(string Id);
public record RejectPersonFailure(string Error);
//...

public static class PeopleReducer
{
    [ReducerMethod] public static PeopleState HandleRejectPerson(PeopleState state, RejectPerson _)
    {
        return state with { IsLoading = true };
    }
    [ReducerMethod] public static PeopleState HandleRejectPersonFailure(PeopleState state, RejectPersonFailure action)
    {
        return state with
        {
            IsLoading = false,
            Error = action.Error
        };
    }
    [ReducerMethod] public static PeopleState HandleRejectPersonSuccess(PeopleState state, RejectPersonSuccess action)
    {
        return state with
        {
            IsLoading = false,
            People = [.. state.People.Where(u => u.Id != action.Id)] //remove person
        };
    }
    //...
}


public class PeopleEffects(IState<PeopleState> state)
{
    [EffectMethod] public async Task OnRejectPerson(RejectPerson action, IDispatcher dispatcher)
    {
        string id = action.Id;

        try
        {
            var http = new HttpClient();
            HttpResponseMessage resp = await http.DeleteAsync($"people/{id}");
            if (!resp.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                throw new ApplicationException("error");
            }

            dispatcher.Dispatch(new RejectPersonSuccess(id));
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            dispatcher.Dispatch(new RejectPersonFailure(ex.Message));
        }
    }
    //...
}

The state is a list of people that can be approved or rejected (user signups). When a RejectPerson action is dispatched, I can see it happening in the Redux DevTools and there the state also updates. But in the UI the child component does not change.
I also tried forcing a refresh when explicitly listening the relevant event, but it also didn't work.
protected override void OnInitialized()
{
    base.OnInitialized();
    ActionSubscriber.SubscribeToAction<RejectPersonSuccess>(this, (action) => StateHasChanged());
}

Though I know, I can just inject the state in the child and this works, I need to understand why it doesnt work when using an input parameter. Any ideas?
Also what completely puzzles me, is that an action triggering the following reducer correctly updates the state and UI. LoadPeopleStateSuccess does a round-trip to the database and gets all data. Basically the same as is done when the parent is loaded.

public record LoadPeopleState(bool Force = false);
public record LoadPeopleStateSuccess(Person[] People);

[ReducerMethod] public static PeopleState HandleLoadPeopleStateSuccess(PeopleState state, LoadPeopleStateSuccess action)
{
    return state with
    {
        IsLoading = false,
        IsLoaded = true,
        People = [.. action.People],
        LoadedAt = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow
    };
}


To fix the issue, you need to make sure that the parent component correctly triggers an UI refresh when the state changes. You counld try doing this by:

In parent, see that you are subscribing to the state change and invoking StateHasChanged() properly.

Make sure the state subscription and method calls are set up correctly so that the UI is refreshed.


Here's somehting you could try:
parent
 @page "/parent"
@inject IState<MyState> State

<ChildComponent StateData="State.Value"></ChildComponent>

@code {
    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        State.StateChanged += OnStateChanged;
    }

    private void OnStateChanged()
    {
        InvokeAsync(StateHasChanged);
    }
}

child
@code {
    [Parameter]
    public MyState StateData { get; set; }
}


Thank you. My IDE complained about the method signature, which I needed to change to private void OnStateChanged(object? sender, EventArgs eventArgs) => InvokeAsync(StateHasChanged);. Unfortunately, this didnt work and the child is still not updating.

@Ganesh - the parent inherits from FluxorComponent so StateChanged is already wired up to call StateHasChanged.`

To maintain synchronisation between components and the Fluxor state,  wire the components into the Fluxor state events.  Fluxor provides the FluxorComponent to do this automatically.
I hope you don't mind but I've refactored and changed your code to create a functional Minimal Reproducible Example.  I've switched to Adding a person because it's easier!
Program [for completeness]:
// Add services to the container.
builder.Services.AddRazorComponents()
    .AddInteractiveServerComponents();

builder.Services.AddFluxor(o => o
  .ScanAssemblies(typeof(Program).Assembly));

var app = builder.Build();

The record objects:
// guess at your Person object
public record Person(string Id, string Name);

public record PeopleState
{
    public bool IsLoading { get; init; }
    public string? Error { get; init; }
    public DateTimeOffset LoadedAt { get; init; }
    
    // switched an Ienumerable as it's immutable i.e. you can't add or remove records
    public IEnumerable<Person> People { get; init; } = Enumerable.Empty<Person>();
}

public record AddPerson(Person person);
public record AddPersonSuccess(Person person);

The Fluxor objects:
public class PeopleFeatureState : Feature<PeopleState>
{
    public override string GetName() => nameof(PeopleState);
    protected override PeopleState GetInitialState() => new();
}

public static class PeopleReducer
{
    [ReducerMethod]
    public static PeopleState HandleAddPerson(PeopleState state, AddPerson action)
    {
        return state with { IsLoading = true };
    }

    [ReducerMethod]
    public static PeopleState HandleAddPersonSuccess(PeopleState state, AddPersonSuccess action)
    {
        List<Person> list = state.People.ToList();
        list.Add(action.person);
        return state with { IsLoading = false, People = list, LoadedAt= DateTime.Now };
    }
}

public class PeopleEffects
{
    [EffectMethod]
    public async Task OnAddPerson(AddPerson action, IDispatcher dispatcher)
    {
        // Fake a long async call to the data pipeline to add the person
        await Task.Delay(2000);

        dispatcher.Dispatch(new AddPersonSuccess(action.person));
    }
}

ShowPeople has lost the Parameter/.  It inherits from FluxorComponent and is wired into IState<PeopleState> change event.  It will render whenever a state change occurs.
@inherits FluxorComponent
@using Fluxor
@inject IState<PeopleState> State

<div class="">
    @foreach (var person in this.State.Value.People)
    {
        <div class="p-2">@person.Name</div>
    }
</div>

Finally Home.  It inherits from FluxorComponent.  I've added a button to dispatch a Add User event, and an alert to show loading.
@page "/"
@inherits FluxorComponent
@using Fluxor
@inject IState<PeopleState> State
@inject IDispatcher Dispatcher
<PageTitle>Home</PageTitle>

<h1>Hello, world!</h1>

Welcome to your new app.
<div hidden="@(!this.State.Value.IsLoading)" class="alert alert-warning">
    Data Loading
</div>

<div class="m-2">
    <button disabled="@this.State.Value.IsLoading" class="btn btn-primary" @onclick="this.OnDispatch">Dispatch</button>
</div>

<ShowPeople />

@code{
    private int counter = 1;

    private void OnDispatch()
    {
        var action = new AddPerson(new(Guid.NewGuid().ToString(), $"Fred-{counter}"));
        Dispatcher.Dispatch(action);
        counter++;
    }
}

Update based on comments
Here's my revised generic ShowPeople:
ShowPeopleAlt.razor

<div class="">
    @foreach (var person in this.People)
    {
        <div class="p-2">@person.Name</div>
    }
</div>

@code {
    [Parameter] public IEnumerable<Person> People { get; set; } = Enumerable.Empty<Person>();
}

And Home:
@page "/"
@inherits FluxorComponent
@using Fluxor
@inject IState<PeopleState> State
@inject IDispatcher Dispatcher
<PageTitle>Home</PageTitle>

<h1>Hello, world!</h1>

Welcome to your new app.
<div hidden="@(!this.State.Value.IsLoading)" class="alert alert-warning">
    Data Loading
</div>

<div class="m-2">
    <button disabled="@this.State.Value.IsLoading" class="btn btn-primary" @onclick="this.OnDispatch">Dispatch</button>
</div>

<ShowPeople />
<ShowPeopleAlt People="this.State.Value.People" />


@code{
    private int counter = 1;

    private void OnDispatch()
    {
        var action = new AddPerson(new(Guid.NewGuid().ToString(), $"Fred-{counter}"));
        Dispatcher.Dispatch(action);
        counter++;
    }
}

This all works because Home inherits from FluxorComponent which registers a handler on the IState service.  This calls StateHasChanged when the OnAddPerson effect completes and invokes the HandleAddPersonSuccess reducer.  this.State.Value.People has changed on ShowPeopleAlt, so the renderer calls SetParametersAsync on the component passing in the latest parameters.


Thank you for this detailed example! I was directly using the store in the child component before which worked great. I changed the code to provide the data from outside via an input parameter on purpose, since I would ike to re-use the component and pass multiple subsets of the data into separate instances of the child component. When using the store directly in the child, my reservation would be, that I basically need to duplicate the child component razor since the store query is more or less hard-wired to the component.

OK, np. [In Jest] If you'd only said that's what you wanted :-).  See my revised answer.  I'm not sure what you're doing wrong in your code as you don't show everything.  I'm assuming ShowPeople is just a display component.  The Add/Remove event is coming from elsewhere.
